# How To Change TimeZone?

Tags: php, dns, timezone, cpanel

i recenty try to find time zone setting in local host and work fine via edit php.ini in apache server local host.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Karachi
```

and geting stuck and i try to find solution for change time zone in domain. but did not get any answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)('Asia/Karachi');

Comment: where i put this ? i mean $date=date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi'); 
? or where ? remember i am asking in domain.

Comment: at the beginning of your code, preferably. This is a run-time configuration change.

Comment: oh if i put this code in my config (data base pasowrd and username) file? is it works? in all files? who include with config.php?

Comment: AwwwwWWW Its Work With Config File Thanks bye :-PPpPp